# Subgroup of $F_2$ with index 2 and 3

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, covering-spaces

$F_2$ is free group with 2 generators. Now I want to know how many subgroup with index 2 it has. And what about index 3. For the latter case, how can I judge whether the subgroup is normal?

I am trying to solve this by considering covering space. For the index 2 case, I actually only get the wedge sum of 3 circles as covering space(or homotopy equivalent to this). I believe there should be others. For index 3 case, I find two kinds of covering space: wedge sum of 4 circles and 3 vertex with 3 circles. So which should be normal?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003319

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This only answers the index 2 case (and does not use covering spaces).

Since every subgroup of index $2$ is normal this can be obtained by calculating how many surjective homorphisms there are from $F_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Since there are only four maps from a two element set $\{x,y\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ there are exactly four homorphisms from $F_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and only three of these are surjective. The three normal subgroups they correspond to are:

$$S_1=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}...x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \alpha_1+...+\alpha_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}$$
$$S_2=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}...x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \beta_1+...+\beta_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}$$
$$S_3=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}...x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \alpha_1+...+\alpha_n+\beta_1+...+\beta_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}.$$

In a similar way one can find all normal subgroups of index 3 but not arbitrary subgroups of index 3.

Answer (score 1):

See [Example 5.3](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/horawa/free_groups_and_geometry-final.pdf#theorem.5.3) and [Example 5.4](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/horawa/free_groups_and_geometry-final.pdf#theorem.5.4)

There are 13 index 3 subgroups of $F_2$, of which 4 are normal.

Proof: These subgroups are in one-one correspondence with degree 3 based covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$. Each is a connected 1-complex, with 3 $0$-cells, each with valence 4. There are 4 such 1-complexes. Now assign an orientation to each edge, and either an $x$ or $y$ label, in such a way that, at each vertex, there is an incoming $x$ edge, an outgoing $x$ edge, an incoming $y$ edge, and an outgoing $y$ edge. Also pick a basepoint. Up to equivalence, the ways of doing this are shown below. Of these, the bottom four are regular.

So, there are 14 index 3 subgroups of $F_2$, of which 4 are normal.
[image]

There are 3 index 2 subgroups of $F_2$, all are normal.

Proof: These subgroups are in one-one correspondence with degree 2 based covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$.

| Subgroup | Covering space |
| --- | --- |
| $$S_1=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}\dots x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}$$ | [image] |
| $$S_2=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}\dots x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \beta_1+\dots+\beta_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}$$ | [image] |
| $$S_3=\{(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}\dots x^{\alpha_n}y^{\beta_n})\,|\, \alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n+\beta_1+\dots+\beta_n\text{ is divisible by }2\}.$$ | [image] |