# Examples where geometry/topology helps algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

I think that the most beautiful parts of mathematics are the ones where algebra and geometry/topology interact with each other. For example, in algebraic topology we often transform geometric problems in algebraic ones, so we could say that in this case "algebra helps geometry". Are there examples the other way around?

I know, for example, that given a commutative ring $R$, we can functorially construct the topological space $\text{Spec}(R)$. But does studying the spectrum through topological methods actually offer algebraic results on $R$ that were harder to find out in a purely algebraic manner? Is it useful in this sense?

More in general, I would like to find out examples where geometry/topology helps algebra.

Comment: The field of mathematics in which algebra and topology are both used ("intersect with each other")  is analysis.

Comment: The solution of Fermat's last theorem is such an example.

Comment: Quillen’s revolutionary work used homotopy theory to give the correct definition of the full K-theory of rings.

Comment: Group cohomology is another example:  interpreting cohomology topologically has been quite fruitful.

Comment: The topology of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, and other spectral spaces, is definitely powerful but mostly from a point-set topology perspective -- not from a truly 'topological perspective' as I am imagining you are after.

Comment: there are parts of mathematical logic which have been helped enormously by geometry. The topos theoretic analysis of logic is wrapped up in geometric ideas.

Comment: The proof of the Weil Conjecture (a very algebraic statement) comes from geometric methods – the main difficulty is to find the correct “topology” to consider (a slightly lesser one is to show that it has all the desired properties). I’d be a little wary of using “the proof of FLT” as an example because it has so many pieces, ingredients and ideas (some of which definitely come from geometry/topology).

Comment: [This is a highly related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580023/examples-of-group-theoretic-results-more-easily-obtained-through-topology-or-geo?rq=1) which essentially asks the same thing except "group theory" instead of "algebra."

Comment: Geometric group theory fits the bill.

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Comment: Perhaps this very elementary theorem is not the sort of thing you're looking for, but it is a useful fact in number theory and the study of continued fractions that  $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ lies between f $\frac ac$ and $\frac bd$.  This is not hard to prove algebraically, but the geometric proof makes it blindingly obvious: https://blog.plover.com/math/mediant.html

Comment: Thank you for all of these insightful comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a favorite example. It's quite tedious to prove using algebraic means the useful fact that

> **Proposition.** Any subgroup of a free group on finitely many letters is free.

On the other hand, one can prove it using topology as follows. Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of the free group on $n$ letters, $F_n$. A rose with $n$ petals has fundamental group $F_n$. By the covering space correspondence, there is a cover $X$ of the rose with $n$ petals with $\pi_1(X) \cong \Gamma$. As $X$ covers a graph $X$ is itself a graph, and so must have free fundamental group.

Comment: Another result related to this is that, you can embed all $F_n$'s inside $F_2$ (by finding an $n$-fold covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$). In fact, you can also embed $F_\infty$ (free group on countably many generators) inside $F_2$. This is quite counter intuitive because the analogous result doesn't hold for abelian group (or more generally abelian categories). You cannot embed a free module of rank $3$ inside a free module of rank $2$.

Comment: I wish I could give you and Dietrich Burde the "best answer", because both your answers were amazing. Unfortunately, I had to choose!

Answer (score 8):

Another less elementary example is the  [$(1,2,4,8)$-theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bott-Milnor-Kervaire_1,2,4,8_Theorem) on division algebras. Here topological methods are very helpful for the proof, e.g., using Bott periodicity.

Answer (score 4):

For proving $a^2+b^2=c^2$ for right triangles, "geometry" can be very helpful:

[image]

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain This is one of the most common proofs.

Comment: I don’t think that this is an interaction between algebra and geometry. Pythagora’s theorem is a purely geometric result and the drawing doesn’t constitute a formal proof, but a neat geometric visualization. Where is algebra exactly here?

Comment: For me the algebra is in the formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$, where I also think of Pythagorean triples and algebraic number theory, and of $a^n+b^n=c^n$. For Pythagorean triples geometry is indeed helpful, to find a parametrisation $a=m^{2}-n^{2},\ \,b=2mn,\ \,c=m^{2}+n^{2}$. Perhaps this would be a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Gromov proved his [theorem on groups of polynomial growth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth) very geometrically.

The theorem states that a group $G$ has a [nilpotent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group) subgroup of finite index (a very algebraic property) if and only if $G$ has [polynomial growth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)) (a fundamentally geometric property.)

It arguably kicked off the entire area of geometric group theory.